# Using the Screenshot API

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I'm using the Screenshot API, in particular `Screenshot.capture(Activity activity)`. This method returns a ScreenCapture object which contains the bitmap of the device screen.

However, Android Studio cannot "resolve synbol" `Screenshot` and `ScreenCapture` and doesn't give me the option of importing these classes.

Looking forward to your answers!

Here's the code

```
package com.example.android;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ScreenCapture sshot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void getScreenshot() {

        Date now = new Date();
        // create a name for the resulting screenshot file which includes the SD card
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        sshot = Screenshot.capture(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the androidx.test.runner.screenshot library in your build.gradle file? Try adding `implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'` into your build.gradle file.

Comment: Hovering the mouse cursor over ```Screenshot``` or ```ScreenCaputre``` brings up a help balloon "Add library 'Gradle:androidx.test:runner:1.2.0@aar' to classpath. Clicking on the link in the help balloon doesn't seem to do anything. Could anyone tell me how to add the library and what is the classpath that it is referring to ? Sorry, if I sound inexperienced - I am.

Comment: Like I've said, add `implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'` into the build.gradle file of your application module. It's usually there: [Project root]/app/build.gradle

Comment: OK thanks for your help- its worked ! but no idea why ? Except maybe class Screenshot and class ScreenCapture were in a library that the building apparatus did not have access to.. So added into build.grade(Module:app the following line inside the dependencies block: ```implementation "androidx.test:runner:1.2.0@aar"``` then synced and it workded